# Jettisoned Tasks Still In Multitasking Bar

Tags: ios, crash

I was inspecting my crash log and noticed several apps appear to have been jettisoned. But looking at the multitasking bar, they are still there. Is there another way I can confirm that inactive apps are actually being jettisoned before my app crashes?  Can this be seen in any of the tools?

Up until now, I assumed my app was being closed without the inactive apps being jettisoned. Now I'm unsure.

### Update

I have, on several occasions, had my crashing app stop crashing after I removed everything from the multitasking bar. I didn't check the crash log in those cases, and I'll have to do that in the future. But it's hard to imagine that that was just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used instruments to see what the memory usage was while my app was running. I can see that real memory in the Memory Monitor reports the amount of real memory being used by each app.

Seeing that several inactive apps were showing memory use, I confirmed that they were in the multitasking bar. I was able to manually delete each one from the bar and saw an immediate response in memory usage. Each deleted app disappeared from the memory usage list.

This answers my question -- Instruments can show how much memory is used by apps that show up in the multitasking bar.

Apparently, the multitasking bar is showing applications that are currently taking real memory. It is not just a launch history.

That being said, I don't understand why Jetsam does not release these apps before killing my running app. I'll post that question later as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The bar is simply a launch history.  It doesnt represent the current state of your device memory except by coincidence.....

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with additional info. My question is still open though. How can I use the available tools to see if the apps have been jettisoned?

Comment: When you say "removed everything" do you mean all items or just your item?

Comment: I removed all items from the bar and then reloaded my application.

Comment: Then you have altered the memory condition of your device by terminating all of the other background apps, so it may not crash because there is more free memory available to work with.

Comment: Then that makes the bar more than a launch history. So my question is  why does the crash log show them jettisoned (jetsam does this to free memory), but they are still in the bar and taking up memory.

Comment: That's exactly what I said...the bar is a launch history...i.e. These are the last programs that you LAUNCHED, but they may or may not be actually running in the background